# how do i replace CARD with a for loop in flutter

Tags: sqlite, flutter, dart, card

i want to replace the card with for loop. here's the body for my screen where i am showing the output

```
body: FutureBuilder<List>
       (
         future: db.getAllRecords("EMPLOYEE"),
        initialData: List(),
        builder: (context,snapshot){
          return snapshot.hasData
              ? ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (_, int position){
                 final item =snapshot.data[position];
                 return Card(
                   child:ListTile(
                     title: Text(
                        snapshot.data[position].row[1]
                     ),
                   ),
                 );
                },
          )
             : Center(
                child:CircularProgressIndicator() ,
              );
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the way you wrote it is the standard way of implementation in Flutter. You could call the default `ListView` constructor instead of `ListView.builder` one and then call the for loop but that's not the best practice.

```
List<Widget> _buildListItems(BuildContext context, List<...> list) {
    final output = List<Widget>();
    for (var item in list) {
        output.add(
            Card(
                child: ListTile(
                    title: Text(item.row[1]),
                ),
            ),
        );
    }
    return output;
}

//... back to your build(context) body

    body: FutureBuilder<List>(
        future: db.getAllRecords("EMPLOYEE"),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
            return snapshot.hasData
                ? ListView(
                    children: [
                        ..._buildListItems(context, snapshot.data),
                    ],
                )
                : Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
        }
    )
```

Comment: well i will be sending text messages to those numbers of the employees(max 5 people) with card i cant do that is there any other way to do so?

Comment: Your comment seems like a completely different issue, unrelated to UI. You can use https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sms to send SMS messages. I'd suggest posting a new question with details as to what you want to achieve.